# Adding always hot outlet to 3 way light

Tags: electrical

Is there a way to power an always hot outlet as shown in diagram? This is exactly how my wiring and switches are layed out.

There is a line from the outlet coming into the (light)box as I have sketched in the picture.

The way it was wired, the switch would always turn off whatever is plugged into the outlet.

I want to outlet to be always hot, not controlled by the switches.

Could someone please show me how to wire, if it is possible?

[image: 3 Way switch with light between]

Comment: You would need to wire the outlet from before the first switch, from the power source.  Everything after that switch is switched hot/travellers.

Answer (score 4):

##### Smart Switches to the Rescue!

An ordinary 3-way switch setup needs three wires:

- Hot *or* Switched Hot *or* Neutral
- Two Travelers

There are a *lot* of different 3-way configurations. In your example diagram:

- Left (top of stairs) to Light

  - Travelers = Black and Red
  - Neutral = White
- Right (bottom of stairs) to Light

  - Travelers = White (with black mark) and Red
  - Switched Hot = Black

with the result that the light gets switched hot and neutral and functions properly. But of course that means a receptacle on the same wires will be switched, which you don't want.

There are really only two solutions: Additional wires or smart switches. Additional wires (which really means additional cables) is often hard to do. With the exception of ground wires, you can't just run an additional single wire, you need to have all wires for a light or receptacle or switch in one cable or conduit.

Smart switches *can* provide a solution. The catch is that there are a *lot* of different ways of designing smart switches. Smart switches to replace a 3-way circuit can:

- Use one smart switch, the existing travelers, with some rewiring in the switch boxes, together with one of the original switches.
- Use two smart switches, the existing travelers, with some rewiring in the switch boxes.
- Use two smart switches, *one* of the existing travelers, with some rewiring in the switch boxes.
- Use two smart switches and *abandon* the wires to the second switch, with the second switch powered by battery (or possibly by reuse of the existing wires) with the two switches communicating wirelessly. (Which often does *not* mean WiFi - there are other types of wireless communications.)

You need one of the last two. What that really means is that one smart switch ("Top of stairs") becomes a single switch for the light (using the red wire as switched hot), the black wire is connected as hot for the receptacle and the "Bottom of stairs" switch is replaced with a smart switch that communicates wirelessly to the other smart switch.

There are a number of name-brand, UL or ETL listed, switches available that can do this. Do NOT buy random stuff from large rivers as it is usually not properly listed and with 120V power that can result in some dangerous situations if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I was afraid there was no solution with the existing wires I have. My other option I will likely do, is take the lead from the outlet from the light box and rewire it into an outlet in the bathroom on the same wall.

Comment: Can't pull from bathroom circuit, supposed to be just for bathrooms.

Comment: Yah, after I posted my comment and thought about it. I remembered what you said, that the bathroom must be just for the bathroom.